# How do I list a computer's remotely shared files using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming, file-sharing, network-share

How do I list a computer's remotely shared files using C#?

Could someone help me with this?

[Update]: Done it by exe "NET VIEW" command in C# code finally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd look at the [Win32_Share](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394435%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class. If you haven't used WMI from C# before, this codeproject article should show you how to get started: [Howto: (Almost) Everything in WMI via C# - Part 1: Registry](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInWMI01.aspx)

This Technet article has a sample VBScript for enumerating shared: [Enumerating Shared Folders](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176593.aspx)
Just change `strComputer` in that sample to be the computer you're interested in.